# How to get the tagname and its href of selected anchor text

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I select a link (with no ids or classes) within a paragraph, I need to get the selected links href value. How do I do it in jQuery?  I am using `document.getSelection()` method for that. But I don't see any method in `document.getSelection()` which returns the href value.

When I select the link by dragging the mouse, I am able to get the href value like below.

```
currentLink = document.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement.href;
```

But when I select the link by double clicking the text, the above command will not return the href value. Please help.

Comment: Example please? Are you clicking on the links or are you highlighting (making a selection) of text in a paragraph? What if there's more than one anchor element in the selection? Once you have the anchor element, you can get the href with jQuery quite simply: `$(anchorEl).attr('href');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I wrote you a little something to get you started. It's more cross-browser than your original code:

```
(function(AnchorSelector, $, undefined) {

    AnchorSelector.getAnchorHrefs = function(e) {
        var container = '';
        if (window.getSelection) {
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            if (sel.rangeCount) {
                var div = $('<div>');
                for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
                    div.append(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
                }
                container = div;
            }
        } else if (document.selection) {
            container = $('<div>').append(document.selection.createRange().htmlText);
        }
        var arr = $.map(container.find('a'), function(n, i) {
            return ($(n).attr('href'));
        });
        if (arr.length) {
            alert(arr.join(','));
        }
        // Note: you can check e.type to see if it was a 'dblclick' or a 'mouseup' 
        // you may need to employ some type of debouncing to not get two alerts
        // when you double click the text
    }

    $(function() {
        $(document)
            .dblclick(AnchorSelector.getAnchorHrefs)
            .mouseup(AnchorSelector.getAnchorHrefs);
    });

})(window.AnchorSelector = window.AnchorSelector || {}, jQuery);
```

​And here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g5fwB/1/).